# Order of items in a very basic robots.txt changing the command scope?

Tags: robots.txt

I had a very simple robots.txt file setup for a site I maintain.   After a spike of traffic that the ISP put down to crawlers they suggested I add a crawl delay directive which is fair enough.  So I ended up with this file

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /a-page-i-wanted-to-ignore
Crawl-delay: 1
```

I still receive spikes in traffic that are causing downtime.  The ISP told me in relation to the robots file I had setup (shown above) that "the crawl delay is configured only for the '/a-page-i-wanted-to-ignore ' page and not for the entire website."

I wanted to check, is that correct?  If a command like crawl-delay placed under a 'disallow' line will it be specific to the disallow clause ?

Answer (score 2):

> The ISP told me that this directive has only defined the crawl delay for the page `/a-page-i-wanted-to-ignore`

That does not make sense. The `crawl-delay` directive has nothing to do with the preceding `Disallow` directive.

The page `/a-page-i-wanted-to-ignore` shouldn't be crawled at all - since it's included in the `Disallow` directive, so if the `crawl-delay` should apply to that page it's in direct contradiction to what the `Disallow` directive does. Maybe if it followed an `Allow` directive - but no, it does not work that way.

Your `crawl-delay` directive applies to the group `User-agent: *`, ie. all bots (that are not defined elsewhere in the `robots.txt` file). That is, all URLs for "all bots". And that's "all bots" that obey the `robots.txt` file. Many "bad bots" don't.

However, the `crawl-delay` directive is only supported by a few bots, so it may not have much of an impact at all. The `crawl-delay` directives is supposedly supported by "[Yahoo!, Bing and Yandex](https://yoast.com/ultimate-guide-robots-txt/#crawl-delay-directive)" - but the lesser known bots (that are perhaps causing you problems) probably don't support this at all.

> the ISP put down to crawlers

You need to find out more precisely (from the access logs) the traffic that was hitting your site during this time... user-agents, IP addresses, the URLs being requested, response codes/size...

Comment: Understood about that page being ignored.    But to be sure about crawl-delay (for the bots that don't ignore it) -  this is a universal command?  It's not possible to specify a crawl delay on certain directories/files ?  What I was told is incorrect ?

Comment: What do you mean by "universal command"? `crawl-delay` is not part of any _standard_. I believe it is a group-member directive that applies to the stated `User-agent`(s) (that define the group). "It's not possible to specify a crawl delay on certain directories/files ?" - That's correct, not possible. "What I was told is incorrect ?" - yes, entirely incorrect. Were you "told" this, or did you get a written/email response? If the later then I would be interested to see it.

Comment: By universal command, I was asking if crawl-delay is a document wide directive within the robots.txt file or if it is used within some kind of context, which is what I understood from what I was told by my ISP.   I will update the question to clarify exactly what they said.

Comment: No, `crawl-delay` is a group-member directive (as mentioned). As opposed to a non-group-member ("universal") directive like `Sitemap`. The "group-member" directives work within the context of a "group". The group is defined by the `User-agent` directives that precede it, which define the bots that should honour the group-member directives that follow. `Disallow` and `Allow` are also group-member directives, just like `Crawl-delay`. Any one bot only matches at most one group.